# SSRS- Report parameter not valid for its type- input parameter, no default/available value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameter-passing, type-conversion, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to create SSRS report where i will input the **CombinedAccountNumber** - which acts as input parameter in the report with no default/available value. I have provided the datatype as **INT** in the report but whereas in the datatype it is nvarchar.

When I run the report, it throws the error: The value provided for report parameter **CombinedAccountNumber** is not valid for its type.
Could anyone please assist where I am going wrong, do I need to fix the query or something while adding the parameter in SSRS report?

Here is the query i am using in the Datasets section:-

```
SELECT
        [QAACTO]
       ,[QAACTA]
       ,[QACKDG]
       ,substring([QACPHA],2,4) as 'Alternate Phone Area'
       ,substring([QACPHP],2,4) as 'Alt Phone Prefix'
      ,[QACPHN] as 'Alt Phone Number'
      FROM [MOCK124].[dbo].[FPQA]
      where 
      ((REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([QAACTO],'0', ' ')),' ', '0'))
      +
      (REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([QAACTA],'0',' ')),' ','0'))
       +
      ([QACKDG])) = @CombinedAccountNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **WHERE** clause is converting the fields to a string. Aren't you merging the fields rather than adding them?

```
 where 
      ((REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([QAACTO],'0', ' ')),' ', '0'))
      +
      (REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([QAACTA],'0',' ')),' ','0'))
       +
      ([QACKDG])) = @CombinedAccountNumber
```

Either convert it or set your parameter to be TEXT. I think the text parameter would be better since your numbers may get too big for an INT.

Comment: Setting the parameter to TEXT throws the error: Query execution failed for dataset. Incorrect syntax near nvarchar. Must declare the scalar variable "@CombinedAccountNumber"                                                                         Please note that all the fields are saved as nvarchar in the database. Please let me know what should i be doing?

Comment: Where do have nVarChar? Is your parameter in SQL? I was thinking it was in SSRS but you had it set to use INTEGER instead of text.

Comment: I meant all the fields in the table(DB) are saved as nvarchar but the report parameter @CombinedAccountNumber is set to INT. I tried changing it into TEXT, both are throwing error. I am thinking it may be because of the fields are nvarchar in the table and the report parameter datatype does not match?? Is there anything else I should try? TIA

Comment: I don't see what you'd be getting an error if the Parameter is TEXT and you're not using a Multi-Value parameter. Maybe try CASTing your fields as nVarChar - `WHERE CAST( (Replace... AS nVarChar(1000))`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by using the same query with Common Table Expression and it solved the problem but yes, the report parameter in TEXT format.
Thanks so much for your input :)